# How do I determine the sector size for unbuffered IO on a file (Windows)?

Tags: c++, winapi

As far as I understand:

- A volume can be mapped to multiple physical disks
- Each physical disk has its own sector size

As mentioned in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-buffering) there is a certain requirement when using unbuffered IO:

> File access sizes, including the optional file offset in the OVERLAPPED structure, if specified, must be for a number of bytes that is an integer multiple of the volume sector size. For example, if the sector size is 512 bytes, an application can request reads and writes of 512, 1,024, 1,536, or 2,048 bytes, but not of 335, 981, or 7,171 bytes.

Now let's say I want to create a new file "D:\Folder\File.txt", whereby D: is a volume mapped to multiple physical disks and I'm planning to use unbuffered writes on that file.

The following assumption may not be true, please correct me if it's wrong.
Since D: spans multiple physical disks, the new file could be written on one disk or another, or it may be split across both.

To fulfill the requirement for unbuffered IO stated previously, the physical sector size needs to be determined in advance, so how is this done in the special case where a file is potentially spread across multiple physical disks with different sector sizes?

Comment: I think you'll find in practice that sector sizes don't vary much. The physical devices have logic to simulate sector sizes that are different than what they use internally.

Comment: [`NtQueryVolumeInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryvolumeinformationfile) with `FileFsSizeInformation` return [`FILE_FS_SIZE_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_file_fs_size_information) and here exist `BytesPerSector`. also `NtQueryInformationFile` with `FileAlignmentInformation` return `FILE_ALIGNMENT_INFORMATION` where exist `AlignmentRequirement` for address of your buffer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the **struct _FILE_STORAGE_INFO** which is returned from **GetFileInformationByHandleEx** is what I was looking for. [Struct is described here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-file_storage_info)